# .get() in .each() loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

My problem is that i have array of String values and I want to iterate over the array and with each value I want to get the id of the value form database.
usernames array has String values in it.

EDIT: After watching topic my post was refered to, i got this code and it still doesnt work, but why??

```
 for(i=0;i<usernames.length;i++){
             $.get("getIdByName.php",
              {name : usernames[i]}).done(function(data){
            ids.push(data);
         });

           }
```

Comment: did you define somewhere ids variable? I didn't see it?

Comment: watched the ohter tpic, but my code which I upgraded form ther dont work. for(i=0;i<usernames.length;i++){
                 $.get("getIdByName.php",
                  {name : usernames[i]}).done(function(data){
                ids.push(data);
             });
          
               }